# Future Method invoked from public visualforce site

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, callout, oauth2

have a public form on salesforce, and I want to make a callout to some API before this form insert a couple of registers, so I wanna know if I can handle future methods annotations from public profiles on Sites with visualforce, this is my code by now:

```
<apex:page controller="ChainedContinuationController" showChat="false" showHeader="false"  action="{!invokeOauth}">
   <apex:form >
      <!-- Invokes the action method when the user clicks this button. -->
      <apex:commandButton action="{!invokeOauth}" value="Start Request" reRender="panel"/>  
   </apex:form>

   <apex:pageBlock title="Informacion de Vehiculo" mode="read">   
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="resultado1">
           <apex:outputText value="{!result1}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="resultado2">
           <apex:outputText value="{!result2}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="resultado3">
           <apex:outputText value="{!result3}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="resultado4">
           <apex:outputText value="{!result4}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="resultado5">
           <apex:outputText value="{!result5}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>       
   </apex:pageBlock> 

</apex:page>
```

So the controller make a couple of chained callouts, for an OAuth Authentication, and then there is a method who call the future Method that create registers on the external API:

```
public with sharing class ChainedContinuationController {
    //Variables de sesion
    public String accessToken_C;
    public String refreshToken_C;
    public String id_objsf;
    //Labels para las llamadas de WS
    public String requestLabel1;
    public String requestLabel2;
    public String requestLabel3;
    public String requestLabel4;
    public String requestLabel5;
    // Resultados de cada llamado
    public String result1 {get;set;}
    public String result2 {get;set;}
    public String result3 {get;set;}
    public String result4 {get;set;}
    public String result5 {get;set;}

public void finalResult() {
        HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(this.requestLabel3);
        // Set the result variable that is displayed on the Visualforce page
        this.result3 = response.getBody();
        // Return null to re-render the original Visualforce page      
        Token_OAuth__c oAutk= [SELECT Id, Name, username__c, password__c, token_access__c, token_refresh__c FROM Token_OAuth__c WHERE Name='carsyncsuite' LIMIT 1];
        oAutk.token_access__c=this.accessToken_C;
        oAutk.token_refresh__c=this.refreshToken_C;
        oAutk.response__c=this.result3;
        update oAutk;
        Map<String, Object> m_send =(Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(this.result3);
        System.debug(m_send.get('value'));
        Map<String, Object> val =(Map<String, Object>)m_send.get('value');
        System.debug(val.get('success'));
        Boolean status_response=(Boolean)val.get('success');
        System.debug(val.get('emailAddressAlreadyExists'));
        Boolean mailExistence=(Boolean)val.get('emailAddressAlreadyExists');

        System.debug(m_send);
        Integer reqStatus= (Integer)m_send.get('requestStatus');

        String resp=this.result3;
        if(reqStatus==1){
            sendInfoLw.getClientId(this.id_objsf);
        }
    }
```

this call the future method:

```
public class sendInfoLw {
    public static String accessToken_C;
    public static String response;

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void getClientId(String id_document) { 
        Token_OAuth__c oAutk= [SELECT Id, Name, username__c, password__c, token_access__c, token_refresh__c, response__c FROM Token_OAuth__c WHERE Name='carsyncsuite' LIMIT 1];
        accessToken_C= oAutk.token_access__c;
        String response = oAutk.response__c;
        Map<String, Object> m_send =(Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);
        System.debug(m_send);
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        Integer reqStatus= (Integer)m_send.get('requestStatus');
        if (reqStatus==1) {
            System.debug('OBTENCION DE ID CLIENTE (getClientId)');
            map<String, Endpoint__c> endPoints = Endpoint__c.getall();
            Endpoint__c endPoint = endPoints.get('getClientIdLW');
            String endPointPtx= (String)endPoint.get('Endpoint__c');
            HttpRequest req_get_client_id = new HttpRequest();
            req_get_client_id.setEndpoint(endPointPtx+id_document+'&page=0&pageSize=10');            
            req_get_client_id.setMethod('GET');      
            req_get_client_id.setHeader('Authorization', 'bearer '+accessToken_C);
            if (Test.isRunningTest()){
                Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new SingleRequestMock(200,
                                                                          'Complete',
                                                                          '[{"status":"OK","message":"Cotización registrada correctamente"}]',
                                                                          null));
                res.setBody('{"status":"OK","message":"Cotización registrada correctamente"}');
            }else{
                res = http.send(req_get_client_id);     
            }        
            String resp_send=res.getBody();    
            System.debug(resp_send);
            m_send =(Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp_send);//Obtengo el objeto Json como Map
            System.debug(m_send);            
            reqStatus=(Integer)m_send.get('requestStatus');
            if(reqStatus==1){
                System.debug(m_send.get('value'));
                Map<String, Object> val =(Map<String, Object>)m_send.get('value');//Obtengo el objeto Anidado value Json como Map
                System.debug(val.get('items'));            
                List<Object> item =(List<Object>)val.get('items');//Obtengo el objeto Items que es un arreglo Json como Map
                System.debug(String.valueOf(item.get(0)));
                Map<String, Object> items =(Map<String, Object>)item.get(0);//Tomo el primer valor de el arreglo items y lo hago Map                
                Integer id_client=(Integer)items.get('id');//Obtengo el id del cliente
                System.debug(id_client);
                sendInstallOrder(items);//Another sending methods
                sendWelcomeMail(items);//
            }

        }
    }


}
```

It seems future method is not triggering for what I can see by now, anyone work with something similar before?

Comment: (1) future should be able to execute from sites; I do this with my webhook responder code that is essentially a public site.  (2) FYI - not best practice to do test.setMock inside of prod code; this belongs in testmethod; (3) in debug log, the future method will appear as a separate log; (4) debug logs for sites require special enablement - see doc

Comment: Hi, thanks, Already set up the special log for the public site and I can debug it, but how can I do to debug the future method consume from public site? can u help me plz

Comment: Each site has implicit "Guest" user associated with them. You would want to add that user and then all debug logs shows up when a public request is made. For ex., 'Community Portal Site Guest User'